# Handling dictionary object in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have following python dictionary object(json schema) - A which is a list of dictionary elements-

```
[
  {
    "id": 101, 
    "type": "fruit", 
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "id": 102, 
    "type": "fruit", 
    "name": "mango"
  },
  {
    "id": 103, 
    "type": "vegetable", 
    "name": "cabbage"
  },
  {
    "id": 104, 
    "type": "vegetable", 
    "name": "carrot"
  }
]
```

Can somebody tell me how can I manipulate this list of dictionary object as I want following as the output B :-

```
[
  {
    "id": 102, 
    "type": "fruit", 
    "name": "mango"
  }
]
```

I tried doing this :-

```
import json

for myObj in A:
   if myObj['id'] == 102:
      myVal = myObj
test = json.dumps(myVal)
my_op = json.loads(test)
```

but this is not working as it is returning me "unicode" as type but I want dictionary "list" as its type.

Solution:-

```
import json

for myObj in A:
   if myObj['id'] == 102:
      myVal = [myObj] # Add myObj to list again which fixes the issue
test = json.dumps(myVal)
my_op = json.loads(test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json

for myObj in A:
   if myObj['id'] == 102:
      myVal = [myObj]
test = json.dumps(myVal)
B = json.loads(test)
print B
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `myVal` into a list again:

```
myVal = [myObj]
```

This produces:

```
[{u'type': u'fruit', u'id': 102, u'name': u'mango'}]
```

after running it through `json.dumps()` / `json.loads()`. The Unicode strings are *entirely normal*; JSON uses Unicode strings throughout.

Comment: I indeed missed adding it to a list again!